# Work-horse terminated unexpectedly; waitpid returned 132 (signal 4);

Tags: python, docker-compose, redis, ubuntu-server, python-rq

I'm having problems using redis queue in my Ubuntu Server 22.04 (running AWS with 16GB of Ram and 4 CPU cores).

I have a web application using docker compose with Python 3.10, Redis 7.0.11, Redis Queue 1.14.0.

In my application I send a task to redis queue that uses EvalML library to find the best ML model for a set of variables.

I think there is a bug with Ubuntu server and RQ. Please if anyone knows anything I would be very grateful.

I tested my webapp correctly inside WSL2 and also MacOS Monterrey using docker compose. However inside Ubuntu Server 22.04 with docker it shows this error

Comment: It is extremely unlikely to be a bug in Ubuntu.  Signal 4 is SIGILL -- illegal instruction.  Are you using any binary libraries?  Do you have the correct libraries for your processor?

Comment: Hello @TimRoberts, thanks for your answer. Regarding binary libraries, what are you referring at? I installed docker compose in my fresh Ubuntu Server 22.04 and then I used docker compose up --build -d. The libraries installed from python are the ones specified in my requirements.txt

Comment: Is your model especially memory-intensive?  Docker containers have a memory limit (which can be extended).

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, it may be intensive but I have 16GB of Ram. I have tried adding the memory limit on the Docker Compose file, however I get the same error. Do you know any other way to extend such memory?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had before a KVM Generic processor from my virtual machine. I asked IT team to enable KVM virtualization and to map the correct Intel processor. Thanks for your help and I hope this helps someone with the same problem.

To check if KVM Virtualization is enabled, user must type on a terminal:

```
lsmod | grep kvm
```